# What's the issue with keeping a SQL Server login's default database as 'master'

Tags: sql-server, logins, tempdb, master-system-database

I've read recommendations to switch non-sysadmins login's default database to something other than master. Tempdb is often recommended.

If a login/user has no permissions by default for their default database, why is it sometimes recommended to change the default database away from master?

Comment: You will face when try to login to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

> If a login/user has no permissions by default for their default
> database, why is it sometimes recommended to change the default
> database away from master?

If the login/user does not have atleast connect permission to the default database you'll face error.

```
Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user ‘login name’.
```

> Why it is recommended to change default database instead of master?

master,msdb,model databases are importent system database that can be some how used to interfare into SQL Server process. That's why for security purpose it is recommended to change default database to tempdb.

Thanks!

Comment: Logins should have connect permissions to their default database by default to my understanding.

If a login hasn't been granted any permissions in these databases and doesn't have a user in them, how could they interfere with SQL Server processes? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: As I mentioned login should have atleast connect permissio to the default database, if the login hasn't be granted any permission you'll see the error and wouldn't be able to login to SQL Server. And so you wouldn't be able to do anything.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't answer my original question of why a login's default database should be changed from the master db to some other db. A login created with default database as master will be able to login without an error. An explicit grant connect permission would not need to be provided for that login. That login will also not have any permissions on the master database.

Answer (score 0):

When no database is specified for the connection, you get into the master database.
When the user database the user wants to switch to is offline, the user remains in the master database whereas otherwise the login would fail, as mentioned by Rajesh. In most cases it is better that the login would fail then that the login continues in master.

For example, when the login concerns a deployment job, it can happen that objects are then unintentionally created on master.
You also would want to avoid any case where the login starts running transactions in the master database, as to avoid filling up the (usually smaller) transaction log.

Comment: A login wouldn't be able to create objects in master if they weren't given specific privilege's to do so, right?

An open transaction could cause the log file to grow since it would prevent truncation, even if it's not touching any data. But I think it would have to be open for an unrealistically long time to cause any issue as not much activity goes on in master.